# How I add new rewriterule in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, plugins

**SOLUTION**: I put this line in .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
-->RewriteRule ^event/([^/d]+)/([^_]*)/?$ index.php?pagename=event&eventid=$1 [QSA]<--
RewriteBase /teatro/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /teatro/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The final url is : www.events.com/teatro/event/2/ExampleEVENT(this is not relevant)/

this is my first question and sorry for my English.
Before start my question I have seen some similar questions about this and I found "the solution" but in my case doesn´t work.
I found this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule

Ok. My question started because I have a plugin in Wordpress (EventBooking) and when I create a new event in the BackEnd the url for default  in the FrontEnd is this:

[www.events.com/teatro/event/?eventid=2](http://www.events.com/teatro/event/?eventid=2)

And I want a friendly url like this :

[www.events.com/teatro/event/[name of event]](http://www.events.com/teatro/event/[name%20of%20event]) (whitout id).

in the .htaccess I have this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /teatro/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /teatro/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the database the name of field of a Event is id not eventid but the original url that works in the frontEnd , is www.mydomain.com/teatro/event/?eventid=2

I think the problem is here. But I don´t know.

I tried add new Rewriterule in functions.php of my theme but doesn´t work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your permalink structure to /%postname%/ and then install this plugin "[CUSTOM POST TYPE PERMALINKS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)", once you have done that, you'll be able to see a new taxonomy under your wordpress permalinks's page through which you'll be able to customize your custom post type permalink's structure, change it to /%postname%/%postname%/ to make it what you're looking to. If the existing existing taxonomy is %event-plugin% then do it accordingly.